# What is the best way to publish and consume different type of messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

**Kafka 0.8V**

I want to publish /consume byte[] objects, java bean objects, serializable objects and much more..

What is the best way to define a publisher and consumer for this type scenario?
When I consume a message from the consumer iterator, I do not know what type of the message it is.
Can anybody point me a guide on how to design such scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I enforce a single schema or object type per Kafka Topic. That way when you receive messages you know exactly what you are getting.

At a minimum, you should decide whether a given topic is going to hold `binary` or `string` data, and depending on that, how it will be further encoded.

For example, you could have a topic named *Schema* that contains `JSON`-encoded objects stored as strings.

If you use `JSON` and a loosely-typed language like JavaScript, it could be tempting to store different objects with different schemas in the same topic. With JavaScript, you can just call `JSON.parse(...)`, take a peek at the resulting object, and figure out what you want to do with it.

But you can't do that in a strictly-typed language like Scala. The Scala JSON parsers generally want you to parse the JSON into an already defined Scala type, usually a `case class`. They do not work with this model.

One solution is to keep the one schema / one topic rule, but cheat a little: wrap an object in an object. A typical example would be an *Action* object where you have a header that describes the action, and a payload object with a schema dependent on the action type listed in the header. Imagine this pseudo-schema:

```
{name: "Action", fields: [
  {name: "actionType", type: "string"},
  {name: "actionObject", type: "string"}
]}
```

This way, in even a strongly-typed language, you can do something like the following (again this is pseudo-code) :

```
action = JSONParser[Action].parse(msg)
switch(action.actionType) {
  case "foo" => var foo = JSONParser[Foo].parse(action.actionObject)
  case "bar" => var bar = JSONParser[Bar].parse(action.actionObject)
}
```

One of the neat things about this approach is that if you have a consumer that's waiting for only a specific `action.actionType`, and is just going to ignore all the others, it's pretty lightweight for it to decode just the header and put off decoding `action.actionObject` until when and if it is needed.

So far this has all been about string-encoded data. If you want to work with binary data, of course you can wrap it in JSON as well, or any of a number of string-based encodings like XML. But there are a number of binary-encoding systems out there, too, like Thrift and **[Avro](http://avro.apache.org/)**. In fact, the pseudo-schema above is based on Avro. You can even do cool things in Avro like schema evolution, which amongst other things provides a very slick way to handle the above `Action` use case -- instead of wrapping an object in an object, you can define a schema that is a subset of other schemas and decode just the fields you want, in this case just the `action.actionType` field. Here is a really excellent description of **[schema evolution](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki/Advanced-usage#schema-evolution)**.

In a nutshell, what I recommend is:

1. Settle on a schema-based encoding system (be it JSON, XML, Avro,
   whatever)
2. Enforce a one schema per topic rule

Comment: Thanks David for a such clear explanation. Im new to kafka. I check the Avro schemas.

Comment: Can I get the schema from the received bytes ? Because i would have hundreds of topics, from the receiver thread, how do i identify which schema to apply?

Comment: No, you can't get a schema directly from the received bytes -- it doesn't carry the schema with it. The "usual" way for Avro is to store the schema in the file with the encoded records, but that doesn't work in a streaming environment. Instead, as alluded to above, I use a separate topic just for Avro schemas. The first thing a consumer does in my system is to listen to this topic from the beginning, and in this way configure itself with the appropriate schemas.