# How can i get the Avro schema object from the received message in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api

I try to publish/consume my java objects to kafka. I use Avro schema.

My basic program works fine. In my program i use my schema in the producer (for encoding) and consumer (decoding).

If i publish different objects to different topics( eg: 100 topics)at the receiver, i do not know, what type of message i received ?..I would like to get the avro schema from the received byte and would like to use that for decoding..
Is my understand correct? If so, how can i retrieve from the received object?

Comment: From what I understand you're trying to wrap your head around Avro and Avro schema management.  I'd suggest to take a look at https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry (whose purpose is to facilitate integrating Avro and Kafka) and the corresponding docs at http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/ and http://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't receive the Avro schema in the received bytes -- and you don't really want to. The whole idea with Avro is to separate the schema from the record, so that it is a much more compact format. The way I do it, I have a topic called `Schema`. The first thing a Kafka consumer process does is to listen to this topic from the beginning and to parse all of the schemas.

Avro schemas are just `JSON` string objects -- you can just store one schema per record in the `Schema` topic.

As to figuring out which schema goes with which topic, as I said in **[a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586251/what-is-the-best-way-to-publish-and-consume-different-type-of-messages/36587402#36587402)**, you want one schema per topic, no more. So when you parse a message from a specific topic you know exactly what schema applies, because there can be only one.

If you never re-use the schema, you can just name the schema the same as the topic. However, in practice you probably will use the same schema on multiple topics. In which case, you want to have a separate topic that maps Schemas to Topics. You could create an Avro schema like this:

```
{"name":"SchemaMapping", "type":"record", "fields":[
  {"name":"schemaName", "type":"string"},
  {"name":"topicName", "type":"string"}
]}
```

You would publish a single record per topic with your Avro-encoded mapping into a special topic -- for example called `SchemaMapping` -- and after consuming the `Schema` topic from the beginning, a consumer would listen to `SchemaMapping` and after that it would know exactly which schema to apply for each topic.

Comment: Thanks David, Could you please provide a code sample for this? Im bit confusing

Comment: What specifically is confusing?

Comment: AFAIU, We will consume messages from 100s of topics, including 'schema' topic? If so, do we need to store the consumed messages (i.e.: avro schemas) from the 'schema'  topic in a queue? Then only we can match the schema with the received data from other topics? I would like to see a java code sample for this

Comment: @DavidGriffin Regarding this: You won't receive the Avro schema in the received bytes

I've read in the Avro spec "Avro data is always serialized with its schema. Files that store Avro data should always also include the schema for that data in the same file"

Is the schema finally traveling with the data or not?

BTW my use case is similar but with RabbitMQ instead of kafka

Comment: It doesn’t travel with the data. For streaming applications you have to manage the scheme separately than the data. For a flat file you can have a header section where you store the schema. But in a stream there’s no concept of a header so you have to store the schemes in a separate place. In my application each stream has a specific schema associated to it, and I have a database that maps avro schema to stream.